# Is there a function that can cancel a square of a number, preserving its initial value?

Tags: functions, roots, square-numbers

When we have the square function defined by :

$y = x²$

This implies $x = \sqrt{y}$ or $x = - \sqrt{y}$, because the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ can have only one image, and does return only a positive value.

We must plot its reciprocal function expressed in the original form :

$x = y²$

[image: plot of square function and its reciprocal]

By doing so we preserve the negative part of the $y$ axis.

But considering that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is the reciprocal function of $f(x) = x²$, we lost this negative part of the $y$ axis.

Then a question comes :

> Is there any manner to cancel a square of a number, preserving its original value ?

Because taken a random number $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$, we would be tempted to say that if they are both reciprocals :

$(x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} = x$

But it's not the case, because if $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ returns only its positive result, then it implies that

$(x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} = |x|$

A form of the equation which does not preserve the initial value of $x$, if $x < 0$.

Comment: No function $f$ can undo squaring for arbitrary real numbers. If there were such an $f$, then since $2^2=4$,  we'd have $f(4)=2$. Also, since $(-2)^2=4$, we'd have $f(4)=-2$. But then $f$ isn't a function, because $f(4)$ has two different values.

Comment: To amplify the comment above: in mathematics, $4$ is $4$ is $4$ is $4$. There isn't a version of $4$ that remembers that we got it by squaring $2$ and another version of $4$ that remembers that we got it by squaring $-2$. There is just $4$.

Comment: Yes, it is obvious.
So it is irrelevant to cancel the square by using $(x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} = x$ ?

Comment: For $~x \in \{-1,1\}, ~y \geq 0,~$ define $~g(x,y) = x \times \sqrt{y}.~$  Then, define (for example) $~f(-2) = (-1,4),~$ and define $~f(2) = (1,4).~$  Then, you have that $~g(x,y^2)~$ is the inverse function to $~f(y).$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean @user2661923.

Comment: By having $~f(y)~$ return a 2nd variable, that represents whether $~y~$ was negative, and by having $~g(x,y)~$ use that 2nd variable, the **sign** of the variable that was sent to $~f(y)~$ has been preserved.  It is simply that the preservation requires that $~f(y)~$ output a second value.  That is $~f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^2.$

Comment: "So it is irrelevant to cancel the square by using $(x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} = x$?" Nobody said it was irrelevant; we are saying it is **impossible** if $x$ could be any real number. In order to recover the sign of $x$, you need to look at something other than just the value of $x^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your response @DavidK.
I learned at school that $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$, may we say that this works only and only if we don't have the case of ($n$ pair, $a=n$ and $b=\frac{1}{n}$) ?

Comment: @user2661923
Thank you, may a trick to get the sign of $y$ like so would be good ? $f(y) = (\frac{|y|}{y}, \sqrt{y})$ for $y \in$ R and $f(y) = (0, 0)$ if $y = 0$ ?

Comment: No reason to complicate it.  Keep it simple.  $~f(-2) = (-1,4), ~f(2) = (1,4),~$ and **arbitrarily**, $~f(0) = (1,0).~$ Don't try to get fancy.  Even though, when $~y \neq 0,~$ the specification $~\dfrac{y}{|y|}~$ comes to the same thing, that is unnecessary.  Simply specify that if $~y < 0,~$ then the first component of $~f(y)~$ is $-1,~$ rather than $~+1.$

Comment: For the various laws of exponents such as $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$, the real problem (pun intended) is that parts of the formulas on either side might not even be defined as real numbers. For example, what is $(−2)^{1/2}$? What is $(−2)^{\sqrt2}$? To be safe, either use integer exponents or use a positive base.